# Moving up and down line in Vim editor HardMode

Tags: vim

I'm learning to use the various movement commands in Vim by disabling the arrow keys and the j,h,k,l movement. I'm unable to use the `),(` keys to move up and down single lines.

I don't want to keep the `w` or `e` keys pressed and am looking for an effective way to move the cursor around.

Can the editor be set to consider each line as a new sentence?

Comment: `1j`, and `1k` will properly do.

Comment: AKA "how do I eat if I sew my mouth shut". Why do that? Sometimes `j` and `k` are what you want. If you don't want to use `j` and `k`, then the thing Hardmode is trying to teach you is "how do I describe the movement in a semantic way". Why do you want to go to the next line? Because there's a variable you want to fix? `/var` will work. There's no one answer to fit all situations (at least not one that makes sense). But that's stupid, as `j` is faster. What you want to train yourself to not do is press `h`/`j`/`k`/`l` repeatedly, not not use them at all.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @andlrc The reason I'm not using `j` and `k` is to learn the other more effective ways of moving the cursor around, HardMode is a Vim plugin which disables the j.k.l.h row and forces you to use the other commands for cursor movement.

Comment: @SY_13 You ask how to move one line, the answer to that is `gj`, `j`, `<CR>`, `<C-j>`

Comment: @andlrc That's interesting. I'll check it out.Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In the future, [vim.se]

Answer (score 2):

`:help sentence` says:

> The definition of a sentence cannot be changed.

However, you can remap `(` and `)` to `j` and `k`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions I read here:

1. How can I effectively move the cursor around in Vim?
2. Can Vim editor be set to consider each line as a new sentence?

To the first, I know it's standard practice in Vim to use the `h, j, k, l` keys to move left, down, up and right respectively. However you could always change this in your `./vimrc` by adding the lines:

```
:nnoremap <previous key> <new key>
```

Eg

```
:nnoremap ( j
```

To the second question, Would you ever need to do that? To explicitly start a new line, you could use the `leader + o` .

Comment: The idea behind diabling the j,k,l,h row was to learn all the other more effective ways to move the cursor in Vim. I was trying to see if there other ways to move cursor up and down one line.

Comment: That's the point: the best way to move cursor up/down one line is `j`/`k`. Hardmode is training you to not care about trivial things like "1 line up", but the why you want to go 1 line up anyway. :p

Answer (score 0):

It's a stupid question (no offense) because `one line` is a graphical representation the purpose of hardmode isn't to disable `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` for shits and giggles. It's to get you to think about navigation by asking *where you want to end up* rather than simply *how do you get there*?

To that extent, you're better off [reviewing methods of navigation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7378/5078)